# Writing into text file on web server using urllib/urllib3

Tags: python, urllib, urllib3

I am wondering if there is a way to write into .txt file on web server using **urllib** or **urllib3**. I tried using urllib3 *POST* but that doesnt do anything. Does any of these libraries have ability to write into files or do I have to use some other library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your question, but I'm assuming that the Python code in question is not running on the web server. (Otherwise, it would be a matter of using the regular `open()` call.)

The answer is no, HTTP servers do not usually provide the ability to update files, and urllib does not support writing files over FTP / SCP.  You will need to be either running some sort of an upload service on the server that exposes an API over HTTP (via a POST entry point or otherwise) that allows you to make requests to the server in a way that causes the file to be updated on the server's filesystem.  Alternatively, you would need to use a protocol other than HTTP, such as FTP or SCP, and use an appropriate Python library for that protocol such as ftplib.

Comment: Thanks for answer :) (Yes it is not running on the server)